Which european countries have closest economic ties with Qatar?
I am looking for information on the strength of EU-Qatar economic ties by country - in absolute terms and in proportion to the total amount of trade or GDP. I am not aiming at a deep economic analysis - just a comparison of importance and potential economic and political influence.
Preliminary research:
Economic and financial relations between Spain and the Cooperation Council for the Arab States of the Gulf: an initial assessment  (specific country)
New west-east route keeps Europe hooked on Russian gas (specific to gas, not by country)
Qatar Major Trade Partners (only some European states)
Qatar and France: Strategic relations, constant coordination (similar summaries can be found for a few EU countries - neither complete, nor very detailed)

Here information regarding Italy, source: Italian Government, Foreign Ministry.
https://www.infomercatiesteri.it/scambi_commerciali.php?id_paesi=112#
https://www.infomercatiesteri.it/paese.php?id_paesi=112
